# Using x5c cert to verify JWT

Tags: rust, jwt

I'm having a hard time authenticating a token using a x5c. (MS OAuth/Azure) Using jsonwebtoken in Rust.

Below is the code...

```rust
// Trying to isolate the problem by only checking the signature. 
let validation_config = jsonwebtoken::Validation {
    algorithms: vec![jsonwebtoken::Algorithm::RS256],
    leeway: 0,
    validate_exp: false,
    validate_iat: false,
    validate_nbf: false,
    aud: None,
    iss: None,
    sub: None
};
let token = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIn...";
let x5c_cert = "MIIDBTCCAe2gAwIBAgIQKOfEJNDyDplBSXKYcM..."; 

let raw_der = base64::decode_config(der, base64::STANDARD).unwrap();
let d = jsonwebtoken::decode::<MsOAuthPayload>(&token, &raw_der, &validation_config);
```

The above always returns InvalidSignature.

- RS265 is the correct algo.
- The cert is correct. I tried it on jwt.io by adding a BEGIN/END cert and it validates fine.
- I used openssl to convert the BEGIN/END pem to DER and the bytes match up from the base 64 decode.
- The key URL is: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys but my specific tenant returns the same keys.

Anyone have some insight on what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

EDIT: Minimal working example here. https://pastebin.com/RqqRaKkU

Comment: Can you check that your code is complete. Three things: What is `MsOAuthPayload`? What is the `der` variable? Should `x5c_cert` be used somewhere?

Comment: Minimal Example posted above and here: https://pastebin.com/RqqRaKkU